# automatic keyboard completion

Tags: 7.5, 7.x

I want to type a friend's name, but the auto-suggest feature of the keyboard insists that I couldn't possibly have spelled that right -- and changes the my friend's name.  How can I tell it to not use the automatic suggestion for this one word only?
[Name of friend is **Dany**, WP7.8 changes that to **Can't**].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type in your friend's name and after the last character of the name typed (and before hitting space), tap the name which gives you and option like this:

[image]

Tapping the `+[Somename]` adds that word to the dictionary and will no longer be auto corrected.

Comment: +1 for picture, that shows the word must be selected to be able to add it.

Answer (score 3):

Click on your friend's name to select it, and you should see an option in the suggestion bar like +Dany. Click +Dany and it will add your friend's name to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (maybe a workaround) is to exit the textbox by touching something outside of it, then entering the textbox again.  Now it doesn't suggest anything and entering a space will not change the word.